# How can I use extended bootstrap 5 colors on Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, colors, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 on an Angular 12 project (with scss), and I can't find a way to use the new extended bootstrap 5 color pallete (like indigo-300 or pink-200 etc.) I don't know if I need to import them somehow or how can I do that on Angular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After asking and check, I arraived to two conclusions:

If you only want to use these colors in a class simple use the variable

```
.custom
{
    color:$indigo-300;
}
```

But if you want to use as primary color, e.g. your styles.scss should be like

```
//see it's necesary import both scss/functions and scss/variables

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

$primary:       $pink-600;
$secondary:     $yellow-300;
$success:       $green;
$info:          $cyan;
$warning:       $yellow;
$danger:        $red;
$light:         $gray-100;
$dark:          $gray-900;

//futhermore it's necesary override the $theme-colors

$theme-colors: (
  "primary":    $primary,
  "secondary":  $secondary,
  "success":    $success,
  "info":       $info,
  "warning":    $warning,
  "danger":     $danger,
  "light":      $light,
  "dark":       $dark
);


@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it turns out I was importing bootstrap's functions and variables the wrong way